# Python json parsing very large files

Tags: python, json

I need to loop through a 30meg json file which is a large file for just text. when simply using. Also I am using a feed from walmart https://developer.walmartlabs.com/docs/read/Special_Feeds. I am not sure if anyone is familiar with this.

`data = json.loads(open('file.json').read())
print data`

I get this error `

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/Desktop/read.py", line 21, in <module>
    data = json.loads(open('rolback.json').read())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 384, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

`

I think it is because the file is so large. 
I have also tried to stream the file and get a memory error.

What options/what is recommended to deal with these very large files? 
Here is a link to a previouse questions that contains some of the output of the file. [python ijson large file loop to get names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806752/python-ijson-large-file-loop-to-get-names)

Comment: Is it a JSON array in the file? or just a set of JSON objects?

Comment: Use jsonlint to verify that you have a valid json file

Comment: Just a set of objects, I am not sure how to use simplejson to get a different error.

Comment: Use `json.load(open('file.json'))` to read from the file as necessary, instead of slurping the entire file into memory before you start parsing.

Answer (score 0):

The `No JSON object could be decoded` error means your json data contains invalid JSON data. 30MB is pretty small and shouldn't be your issue.

You can use simplejson to get a better error message in order to see exactly where your json contains an error.

Comment: Yes. I agree. JSON doesn't have a problem with large files.

Comment: @user3667569 Please use the +1 button instead of writing a comment if you agree with the answer. Thanks !

Comment: My comment was - JSON doesn't have a problem with large files which was not there in your initial answer.