# Casting nltk.bigrams as a list fails when using pdb

Tags: python, nltk, pdb

I've been trying to use python's debugger while learning the nltk library.  I am using Python 2.7.10 and nltk 3.2.5.

When I'm in `pdb` debugging a file, I get anomalous errors.  For example if I have an empty file, `empty.py`:

```
$ cat empty.py 
$ 
$ python -m pdb empty.py 
(Pdb) import nltk
(Pdb) nltk.bigrams([1,2,3,4,5])  # Seems like it is the correct object type
<generator object bigrams at 0x11135d0f0>
(Pdb) list(nltk.bigrams([1,2,3,4,5]))  # However it fails here.
*** Error in argument: '(nltk.bigrams([1,2,3,4,5]))'
```

However, if I do this same thing in the python interpreter:

```
>>> import nltk
>>> list(nltk.bigrams([1,2,3,4,5]))
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

Question : Why does `list(nltk.bigrams())` fail in pdb when it still works in the normal python interpreter?

Comment: What is pdb? Python debugger?

Comment: Is it the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130745/convert-generator-object-to-list-for-debugging/24130771