# Group consecutive integer numbers in a list with a specific tolerance between them Python3

Tags: python

I would like to group consecutive numbers from a list with a tolerance of 3 between elements of the list.
Example : having a list like [242, 243, 244, 246, 2933, 2936, 2937, 2938] I want to have a result like [[242, 243, 244, 246],[2933, 2936, 2937, 2938]]

I am using this code but it gives me errors :

```
def groupEl(list1, tol): 
    res = [] 
    last = list1[0] 
    for ele in list1: 
        if ele-last <= tol: 
            yield res 
            res = [] 
        res.append(ele) 
        last = ele 
    yield res
```

I get on terminal an error message like this :
<generator object split_tol at 0x7f359d7f2550>
Please help!

Comment: Thats not an error! :) The yield keyword returns a generator-object. If you want to see it as a list you can simply write: `return res`

Comment: thank you @SerialLazer even when I replace yield with return I still don't have what I want. I did some changes at the code and now it gives me only the first group of consecutive numbers, not all groups. The line I chenged is :                                                                               `if ele - last > tol`

Comment: Thats because the logic seems incorrect, trying debugging

Comment: You can use `yield`, just call the function as `list(groupEl(...))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding generators in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130745/convert-generator-object-to-list-for-debugging

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is exactly the opposite than what you want here `ele-last <= tol`. and even after this, you will only receive one list and not all.

This will help you:

```
def groupEl(list1, tol): 
    res = [] 
    temp=[]
    last = list1[0] 
    for ele in list1: 
        if abs(ele-last) > tol: 
            res.append(temp)
            temp=[]
        temp.append(ele) 
        last = ele 
    res.append(temp)
    return res
```