# Find elements by using 2 keywords in json

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary, key

Create a function called get_laureates() that thas three parameters:dict_prizes (positional parameter)
year (keyword parameter with default None)
category (keyword parameter with default None)

The function should find all laureates that received the Nobel Prize, optionally in a specific year and/or category (specified using the keywords year and category). It should return a list of the full names of the laureates.

For example, for the year 2018 and category "peace" it should return the list ['Denis Mukwege', 'Nadia Murad'].

```
f = open('/content/laureate.json')
  
dict_laureates = json.load(f)

def get_laureates(year, category):
    for element in dict_laureates['laureates']:
        for k in element['prizes']:
            if (k['category'])  == category and k['year'] == year:
            
                return (element['firstname'] + " "+ element['surname'])
                   

get_laureates(year = "2005", category = "chemistry")
```

it does not work when there are more than 1 output. Any ideas on how to fix this?

however it does not work if there are more than 1 output. Any idea how to modify the code that it outputs all with given criteria?

Answer (score 0):

> *it does not work when there are more than 1 output.*

For sure! Have you ever heard of the keyword [`yield`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)?

Just replace `return` with `yield`, and the function will give you back all the names with a tuple.

---

To convert a generator to a `list`, simply use `list` function.

```
result = list(get_laureates(year="2005", category="chemistry"))
```

If you want to iterate on the generator, simply don't convert it and use the `for ... in` syntax.

Comment: <generator object get_laureates at 0x7f07c55d6450>            thats what i get with yield

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130745/convert-generator-object-to-list-for-debugging, or simply use list(generator)